# Specifying intervals on JQuery Mobile Slider

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-mobile, dhtml

How would I go about doing this? For instance I want a slider with the options in intervals of 15, rather than 1. 
Ex:

```
|------|------|------|------|------|
0      15     30     45     60    75
```

Comment: The HTML5 `input[type=range]` supports the `step` attribute. Could you try adding this?

Comment: nvm I found a quick fix [link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-slider-does-not-support-step-attribute)

Comment: post it as the answer and select it to close the question

Comment: got to wait for the timed limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found a quick fix [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-slider-does-not-support-step-attribute). I really hope they add it to the official release.